# UI Ideas to allow user to select the alignment of text

Tags: forms, alignment

I have a feature in my application which allows user to select alignment or location of the text before printing. E.g. Top Left, Top Right.

Right now, I have created a simple switch like the image below.
[image: Alignment UI]

This is obviously less intuitive than dropdowns, even if it looks slightly better.

I was thinking if there is a better approach that I can try. Maybe 4 radio buttons aligned in 2 by 2 table?

Edit:
Decided to do something similar to Office, but with colors instead of icons.
[image: New Style]
Color scheme is the default scheme of the website, so that's a plus. I am thinking, I can add tooltip as well, to help the user understand it better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the typical Office style way of aligning text. Don't deviate from things that are very common. Most WYSIWYG text editors also implement something like that.

[image: horizontal text alignment in Microsoft Word]
[image: vertical and horizontal text alignment in Micrsoft Word]

You could even consider giving these options in a menu that can be opened from the container that contains the text.

Comment: Funny thing, I totally forgot how Office style alignment works. Did the same for just 4 with nice looking blocks, instead of plain icons. It definitely looks and works much better.